# Prove that if $X,Y\triangleleft G$ and $G=XY$ that $X\cap Y=\{e\}$ then $G\cong X\times Y$.

Tags: group-theory

I had a midterm exam today about group theory and I were asked to prove the following theorem:

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove that if $X,Y\triangleleft G$ and $G=XY$ that $X\cap Y=\{e\}$ then $G\cong X\times Y$.

I really have no idea where to start proving this theorem. Also I tried to find a previous thread about this question but without any luck.

How to prove this theorem?

Comment: It must be a duplicate. However, a hint: show that each element $g$ of $G$ can be *uniquely* written as $g=xy$ with $x\in X, \, y\in Y$, and show that this mapping $g\mapsto (x, y)$ is a group homomorphism. The key is that $[x, y] \in X\cap Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove first that $(x,y) \in X \times Y \longmapsto xy$ is a bijection. Then, note that $xyx’y’=(xx’)((x’^{-1}yx’)y’)=(x(yx’y^{-1}))(yy’)$, thus $(x’^{-1}yx’)y’=yy’$ (Because we have a bijection and the subgroups are normal) and thus the bijection is a homomorphism.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? I don't see it for some reason.

Comment: What is your issue?